# ip6tables on IPv4 only host

Tags: iptables, ipv6

If external interface has only IPv4 address assigned and IPv6 automatic link local, does it make sense to set up ip6tables? I'm asking as I am not sure how it works exactly. If, for example some encapsulating technology is used to provide 6-to-4 connection from IPv6-only endpoint, then on the host inbound interface will it show up as IPv4 or v6 address? Or just to play safe and DROP all IPv6 INPUT traffic?

Comment: It makes the most sense to setup `ip6tables`, and then setup IPv6 connectivity.

Comment: What if I want to keep the host IPv4 only? In this case is ip6tables gonna ever be used?

Comment: That isn't a practical option.

Comment: Aside being practical or not. I would assume that ip6tables would not be used at all then. Am I correct then?

Comment: It's usually not good practice to create your firewall rules manually. There are good firewall builders such as firewalld and ufw which will take care of most scenarios for you (and also correctly firewall IPv6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have an IPv4 firewall, configure an IPv6 firewall like ip6tables. Not doing so is like having a second door to a space that you do not lock because you have not seen anyone use it yet.

Know your network's flows and set firewall policy accordingly. Dropping all traffic may break things. Disabling IPv6 on the interface is better because it will not pull addresses at all.

Creating an IPv6 address plan and using it is better still. You can create logically laid out subnets for your sites and zones, then firewall based on that.